# angularjs add a model layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-scenario

I am using angular with rails backend and I am using $resource to interact backend API. so I have a User service which is a $resource instance

```
App.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/users/:id',{id: '@id'});
}])
```

Now I can use **User** to interact with rails API. but the problem is all the actions in User end with a HTTP request to rails. There is scenario where I just want to create a instance of this model, but not interacting with rails. in the convention of rails, I need a

```
User.new
```

which return a user object, but **NOT**

```
User.create
```

which will save this object to server.

The idea case is I can do the following:

```
var user = User.new({attr1: value1, attr2:value2.....});// new a User instance with supplied value
var promise = User.create(user) // save this user instance to server
```

#### How this could be achieved?

Comment: try `var user = new User({ attr1: value})`, `user.$save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as apneadiving pointed out, the resource instance do the trick!

```
var user = new User({ attr1: value}), user.$save
```